# Como hacer la operación de busqueda e inserción en un arbol n-ario?

Tags: c++, insert, nodos

Necesito saber como hacer las operaciones de búsqueda y de inserción de forma recursiva en un arbol general o n-ario, partiendo de que los nodos se interconectan con los apuntadores hijo y hermano.

He probado hacerlo como si fuera un arbol binario pero no me funciona y al hacer la búsqueda me sale mucha basura.

```
    void Arbol_Multicamino::Insertar()
        {
        cout<<"\nInserte el Nombre del estudiante."<<endl;
        string nom;
        cin>>nom;
        cout<<"\nInserte la Edad del estudiante."<<endl;
        int ed;
        cin>>ed;
        cout<<"\nInserte LA FACULTAD del estudiante."<<endl;
        string fac;
        cin>>fac;
        Nodo *NuevoNodo;
        NuevoNodo=new Nodo(nom,ed,fac);

        if(Raiz==NULL){
            Raiz=NuevoNodo;
            cout<<"\nSe ha insertado un nodo en la raiz (Padre)";
        }
        else{
                string Padre;
                cout<<"\nEsriba el Nombre del Padre para insertar hijos: ";
                cin>>Padre;
                if(Raiz!=NULL)
                {
                    Nodo *Aux=Raiz;
                    Nodo *Temp;
                    Temp=Buscar(Aux, Padre);
                    if(Temp->hijo==NULL){
                        Temp->hijo=NuevoNodo;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(Temp->hijo!=NULL && Temp->hermano==NULL){
                            Temp->hermano=NuevoNodo;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
    }
    //Partimos de que Temp es igual a la raiz...

Nodo* Arbol_Multicamino::Buscar(Nodo *Temp,string Padre)
{
    ///Nodo *Temp=Raiz;
    if(Temp!=NULL)
    {
         if (Temp->Nombre == Padre)
        {
             return Temp;
        }
        else
        {
            Buscar(Temp->hijo, Padre);
            Buscar(Temp->hermano, Padre);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Y el error es que cuando inserto un nodo en la raiz y uno como su hijo no lo muestra bien y se crashea...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Seria muy útil que proporcionaras mas información: por lo menos el código del constructor.
Pero suponiendo que todo el resto del código esta implementado de forma correcta: Su código tiene los siguientes problemas:

1. La inserción no es recursiva, si no que hace uso de una búsqueda recursiva: no estoy seguro si esto es lo que deberias estar implementando.
2. El retorno de la funcion 
   `Nodo* Arbol_Multicamino::Buscar(Nodo *Temp,string Padre)` es un puntero a Nodo, y el criterio de parada lo retorna en 0, su Temp en la funcion  `void Arbol_Multicamino::Insertar()`en la linea `Temp=Buscar(Aux, Padre);` corresponde a una dirección de memoria, por lo que le estaría asignando la dirección de memoria 0 al puntero temp.
3. No estoy seguro de la implementacion que se quiere lograr con hermano. Seria mucho mas lógico simplemente tener referencias a los nodos hijos. Si tienes que tener referencia a los nodos hermanos, ten en cuenta que todo nodo nuevo resulte hermano de otro, también es hijo de su padre, y esa relación la debes agregar.
4. un nodo puede tener n hijos, guardadados por referencia, por lo que hijos nescesita ser un puntero doble.

**edit:**

5. De la busqueda, si el padre es encontrado se retorna el padre, pero ahora debemos buscar el ultimo hermano en caso de que el nodo hijo ya exista, por lo tanto deberias definir una funcion, buscarhermano, donde recursivamente se llegue al ultimo hermano. 
   `if(Temp->hijo!=NULL && Temp->hermano==NULL)`
   Carece de sentido, dado que estarias checkeando el hermano del padre.
6. Esta incializando el puntero a hijos y hermanos a NULL en el ctor?

Comment: Bueno, si tiene razón sobre que retorna un cero cuando es un apuntador de tipo nodo. Con el puntero hermano, solo añado a los demás Hijos de un padre, el primero que apunta a hijo sirve de referencia par añadir a los demás. y de cada uno puede tener varios hijos.

Comment: Okay. En base a esa logica el error esta en que si el padre es encontrado, se retorna el nodo padre. Luego si el nodo padre tiene un hijo, en la condicion             `if(Temp->hijo==NULL){
                        Temp->hijo=NuevoNodo;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(Temp->hijo!=NULL && Temp->hermano==NULL){
                            Temp->hermano=NuevoNodo;` usted estaria fijandose si el padre tiene un hermano